# VBA Standard Function Referencing a Missing Object Library

Tags: vba

Would someone be able to provide some advice on how to deal with the below error? I've been trying to get a .xlsm file (created by another user) to run on my computer, but I'm encountering the error below. I am unable to remove the Missing Library and can't get the code to run successfully. I'm not exactly sure why a standard function would be referencing this missing library. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try changing it to `VBA.Format` instead.

Comment: This happens when libraries use the same name for methods as already exist in VBA.  The compiler can't work out which method you want so you have to qualify the method name with the library name to keep the compiler happy.  Just as @braX has suggested.